# Assistance solving $x'(t)=t-x(t)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm taking a second level ODE class and for part of some problem I need to solve a nonlinear first-order differential equation, but I've never worked with nonlinear problems before (there was no prerequisite to the class for such).

I need assistance to solve $x'(t)=t-x(t)^2$ if someone can run me though the basics on how to get a solution. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: This is so-called [Riccati equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation), which cannot be solved in elementary functions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946040/properties-of-the-solutions-to-x-t-x2 for the directly accessible properties of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, you are trying to solve a [Ricatti differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html) which can be simplified into an [Airy differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html), whose solutions can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

One of the most general cases of the Ricatti differential equation is
$$
x' = P(t) + Q(t)x + R(t)x^2.
$$
For our case, $P(t) = t$, $Q(t) = 0$ and $R(t) = -1$. The transformation
$$
w := -\frac{y'}{yR(t)} = \frac{y'}{y}
$$
leads us to
$$
\frac{y''}{y} - \frac{y'}{y^2}y' = t - \left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)^2 \Rightarrow y'' = ty,
$$
which is the Airy differential equation with $k^2 = 1$. Their solutions are
$$
y(t) = c_1\mathrm{Ai}(t) + c_2\mathrm{Bi}(t),
$$
being $\mathrm{Ai}(x)$ and $\mathrm{Bi}(x)$ the Airy and Airy Bi functions, respectively. Retrieving our $x(t)$ variable and absorbing constants, finally we have
$$
\boxed{x(t) = \frac{\mathrm{Ai}'(t) + c_1\mathrm{Bi}'(t)}{\mathrm{Ai}(t) + c_1\mathrm{Bi}(t)},}
$$
with
$$
c_1 = \frac{\mathrm{Ai}'(t_0) - x(t_0)\mathrm{Ai}(t_0)}{x(t_0)\mathrm{Bi}(t_0) - \mathrm{Bi}'(t_0)}\tag{1}\label{eq:constant}
$$
for some fixed $x(t_0)$ value.

Here is a plot of the result setting $0 \le x(0) \le 2.5$ with steps of $0.25$.

[image: Ricatti equation solution]

For this case, you can simplify \eqref{eq:constant} since
$$
\mathrm{Ai}(0) = \frac{1}{3^{2/3}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}, \qquad \mathrm{Ai}'(0) = -\frac{1}{3^{1/3}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}, \qquad \mathrm{Bi}(0) = \frac{1}{3^{1/6}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}, \qquad \mathrm{Bi}'(0) = \frac{3^{1/6}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}.
$$