# Properties of the solutions to $x'=t-x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f_c$ be the solution to 
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x'=t-x^2 \\ 
x(0) =c 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I'm trying to prove:

1. If $c \geq 0$ then $f_c(t)$ is defined for all $t>0$
2. There is a unique $c_0$ such that $f_{c_0}(t)$ is defined for all $t>0$ and $\lim_{t\to +\infty} (f_{c_0}(t)+\sqrt t) =0$.

Comment: Is $f_c$ meant to stay into a particular set of function (i.e. $\mathcal{C}^1, \mathcal{C}^2, \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$)?

Comment: $f_c$ has to be continuous so just $C^1$

Comment: $\mathcal{C}^1$ is when botn $f_c$ and $f'_c$ are continuous... maybe $\mathcal{C}^0$?

Comment: yes, I meant $C^0$

Comment: A differentiable solution $x$ is automatically $C^\infty$. This is because, if $x$ is differentiable, then $x' = t - x^2$ is a combination of differentiable functions, so $x'$ is differentiable. But then, $x'' = (t - x^2)' = 1 - 2 x \cdot x'$ is a combination of differentiable functions, so $x''$ is differentiable. Continuing in this way, you get that $x$ has derivatives of all orders.

Comment: More generally, you could check that, for a differential equation of the form $x' = F(t,x)$, where $F$ is a $C^\infty$ function of two variables, any differentiable solution $x$ is already $C^\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solutions with $c\ge 0$ drop below $\sqrt{t}$ and stay between $0$ and $\sqrt{t}$

For every $c\ge 0$ there exists $t_0$ such that $f_c(t_0)=\sqrt{t_0}$. Furthermore, $f_c(t)>\sqrt{t_0}$ for $0\le t<t_0$ and $0\le f_c(t)<\sqrt{t_0}$ for $t>t_0$

**Proof**. By the initial condition, $f_c(0)\ge 0=\sqrt{0}$. Thus, if no $t_0$ exists, then $f_c (t)>\sqrt{t}$ for all $t>0$. According to the ODE, this implies $f_c(t)'<0$, so $f_c$ is decreasing, hence $f_c(t)\le c$ for all $t>0$. But $\sqrt{t}$ is unbounded; a contradiction.

So, let $t_0$ be the first $t$ such that $f_c(t_0)=\sqrt{t_0}$. By construction, $f_c(t)>\sqrt{t_0}$ for $0\le t<t_0$. Suppose that there is $t>t_0$ such that $f_c(t)=\sqrt{t}$; let $t_1$ be the smallest such $t$. Then $f_c'(t_1)=0$, which implies that in some neighborhood of $t_1$, the function $f_c(t)-\sqrt{t}$ is decreasing. But this is impossible, because $f_c(t)-\sqrt{t}<0$ for $t_0<t<t_1$.

Finally, since $f_c'(t)>0$ for $t>t_0$, it follows that $f_c$ never becomes negative. In fact, $t_0$ is its point of minimum, with the minimum value being $\sqrt{t_0}$.

#### Solutions with $c\ge 0$ exist globally

Global existence of solution follow from the Picard theorem, because

1. the right hand side $F(x,t)=t-x^2$ is Lipschitz on bounded rectangles;
2. on any interval $[a,b]$ the solution stays within the rectangle $[a,b]\times [0,\sqrt{b}]$.

#### Uniqueness of $c_0$ such that $f_{c_0}(t)=-\sqrt{t}+o(1)$ as $t\to\infty$

By the above, such $c_0$ must be negative. If $b<c_0$, then $f_b(t)-f_{c_0}(t)$ is a decreasing function of $t$, since smaller values of solution yield smaller values of derivative in the negative range. Hence, $f_b(t)-f_c(t)$ is bounded above by $b-c_0<0$, and since $f_{c_0}(t)+\sqrt{t}$ converges to zero, $f_{b}(t)+\sqrt{t}$ cannot converge to zero.

#### Existence of $c_0$ such that $f_{c_0}(t)=-\sqrt{t}+o(1)$ as $t\to\infty$

The set $U=\{c : \exists t>0 \ f_c(t)>-\sqrt{t}\}$ is open: this follows from the continuity of $f_c$ with respect to $c$. The only possible candidate for $c_0$ is $\inf U$. That $U$ is bounded below can be shown as follows:

1. The IVP $x'=1-x^2$ with $x(0)=-2$ has solution $x(t) = \frac{e^{2t}+3}{e^{2t}-3}$ which escapes to $-\infty$ at $t=\frac12\ln 3<1$.
2. The IVP $x'=t-x^2$ with $x(0)=-2$ has solution that stays below the solution in item 1 on the interval $[0,1]$; therefore, it must also escape to $-\infty$.

So, $\inf U\ge -2$.

I don't see a direct proof of the fact that for $c=\inf U$ the solution is asymptotic to $-\sqrt{t}$. The standard reduction of Riccati equation to 2nd order linear equation (which turns out to be the Airy equation) relates this fact to the existence of an [Airy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) that is $o(1)$ as $t\to\infty$.

---

#### Solutions with $c\ge 0$ satisfy $f_c(t)=\sqrt{t}+o(1)$ as $t\to\infty$

Since we already know that solution drops below $\sqrt{t}$, it suffices to prove: if $c\ge 0$, then
$$
f_c(t)>t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2},\quad t\ge 1 \tag{1}
$$
Let $g(t)=t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2}$. The key point is that $g$ satisfies the inequality 
$$g'(t) < t-g(t)^2,\quad t>1\tag{2}$$
because 
$$g'(t)=\frac12 t^{-1/2}+\frac12 t^{-3/2} < 1$$
and 
$$
t-g(t)^2 = t - t + 2 - t^{-1} >1 
$$
By virtue of (2), $f_c-g$ cannot change sign from positive to negative: at a point where $f_c=g$, the inequality  $f_c'>g'$ holds. And since $f_c(1)>0=g(1)$, it follows that $f_c>g$ on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but the second statement was actually supposed to be $f_{c_0}+sqrt t \to 0$... Thank you for your answer! I just have one question, the sign of $x(0)$ doesn't matter? Either way the solution in defined in all of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: (1) I only consider positive times; (2) my argument is based on the assumption $c\ge 0$. For the rest, you are on your own.

Comment: Anyway, I expanded my answer to say a few things about $c<0$.

Comment: Why does "the function $f_c(t)−\sqrt{t}$ is decreasing"  contradict "$f_c(t)−\sqrt{t}<0$"?

Comment: @nbubis I may have explained it clearer in [the other answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/949910/147263). This $t_0,t_1$ business in the first part is just obscuring a simple observation about the nullclines. Namely: when a solution curve crosses the nullcline $x=\sqrt{t}$, it has zero slope. But the nullcline itself has positive slope. So, the solution curve can only cross going from above to below the nullcline.